# Where is it indicated that Charlotte has difficulty choosing between Albert and Werther?

Tags: character-analysis, german-language, johann-wolfgang-von-goethe, the-sorrows-of-young-werther

I read [*The Sorrows of Young Werther*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sorrows_of_Young_Werther) for my literature class (our translation was from Corngold and its title substituted "Sufferings" for "Sorrows", but it's the same story). For a quiz I answered that Charlotte didn't have a difficult time choosing between Albert and Werther. From my reading the narrator was unreasonably getting his hopes up due to her kindness/pity, while she was devoted to her fiancé/husband. However, I got that question wrong.

How can this book be read to support the idea that Charlotte actually struggled in her choice between the men?

Comment: Have you asked your teacher/professor yet?

Comment: @cmw he's been out sick for over a week